# Include Javascript file reference while using url routing asp .net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, url-routing, system.web.routing

I am using url routing in my asp .net 4.0 application.

And I am using following referrence to call my javascript file.Its working fine in my devenv but when i Host in IIS .my javascript function in  the file are not implemented

```
         <script type='text/javascript' src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/js/MYValidations.js") %>'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css"  runat="server" />


I am getting this error
```

The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>). 
        [HttpException (0x80004005):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

start the code block with <%# instead of <%= :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%# ResolveUrl("~/js/MYValidations.js") %>'></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%# ResolveClientUrl("~/js/MYValidations.js') %>"></script>
```

Comment: That worked.But still my functions in referrenced javascript file are not implemented.Can you help me.

Comment: see in debug bar your javascript file is load or not

Comment: my file source is coming empty i.e., src='' .any hints why is it happening

Comment: which one you are using 1st or 2nd?

Comment: @Cherry sorry it was my mistake.Check my updated code src='<%# %>' use single quote

Comment: tried with both. @sangram parmar ya i tried with single quotes only.

Comment: Check updated code..@Cherry sorry it was my mistake.Check my updated code src='<%# %>' use single quote

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35595/discussion-between-sangram-parmar-and-cherry)